# Kendo Tab Scrollable not showing

Tags: kendo-tabstrip

i am using a bit old version of jquery kendo ui.My version is 2014.3.1411. Scrollbar is never showing when overflow occurs.it is coming in the next line.

i tried in different ways..but it doesn't work.

I uploaded a sample project.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsUSBVUzSefxgTvg1Ob-VPmWYuz0?e=StE2BG.

Is it the version issue.Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Scroll Function was not available in R2014 . Take a look a the dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/idoZUtuh

Functionality was introduced in R2017